# Realisability of Representations of PGL(2,q).

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-fields

I was wondering if all complex irreducible representations of $PGL(2,q)$ are defined over $\mathbb{R}$? For example this is not true for $PGL(3,2)$. I believe a name for this type of group is 'totally orthogonal'.

I have searched for quite large $q$ in magma and it seems that the complex irreducible character tables all have Frobenius-Schur index 1, which supports the conjecture.

If this is the case, I would really appreciate a reference, or even just a reference to a good treatment of the complex representation theory of $PGL(2,q)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when $q$ is odd, the irreducible representations are described here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_projective_general_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field

You certainly may compute the Schur index from this...